# Weak topology on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, weak-topology

It is known that $\mathbb{R}$ is a Hilbert space.

My question is: does weak and strong topology are the same thing in $\mathbb{R}$? If not, what does mean weak topology on $\mathbb{R}$?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: On any finite dimensional normed linear space weak and norm topologies coincide.

Comment: Could you please provide an example on infinite dimension Hilbert space?

Comment: An even stronger statement than the one @KaviRamaMurthy mentioned is true: On a finite-dimensional vector space (over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$) there is exactly one Hausdorff topology that makes addition and scalar multiplication continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be a Banach space (this includes $\mathbb{R}$, Hilbert space). Consider the space of all continuous linear functional on $X$ and denote it by $X^*$.

You already have a topology on $X$ which is induced by its metric linear (here the metric means norm) structure. However, sometimes this topology is too strong (contains more open sets) that are required to maintain the continuity of each members of $X^*$. The weakest topology (the least open sets) that is needed to maintain the continuity of each members of $X^*$ is called weak topology on $X$.

**However**, in case of finite-dimensional Banach spaces, the norm topology and the weak topology coincides. Thus, in your case $\mathbb{R}$ with weak topology is nothing but the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$ ($\mathbb{R}$ is a one-dimensional space over itself), induced by the modulus metric.

Comment: Coul you please provide an example of infinite dimensional Hilbert space?

Comment: Infinite-dimensional $\ell_2$ space. In particular, every infinite-dimensional Hilbert space is isometrically isomorphic (no difference as normed linear spaces) to $\ell_2$. The $\ell_2$ is the collection of all those sequences whose square sum is convergent. They are known as square summable sequences. Note that $\ell_2$ is a particular case of $\ell_p$ ($p$-summable sequence)  spaces ($1\leq p \leq \infty$). For $p\neq 2$ these spaces are not Hilbert but Banach spaces.

Comment: @pmun Every infinite-dimensional *separable* Hilbert space is isometrically isomorphic to $\ell_2$ (in the sense of $\ell_2(\Bbb N)$, i.e. the set of functions $f:\Bbb N\to\Bbb R$ such that $\sum_{k\in\Bbb N}\lvert f(k)\rvert^2<\infty$, endowed with the obvious stuff). In general a Hilbert space is isometrically isomorphic to $\ell_2(S)$ for some set $S$ of the appropriate cardinality, where by $\ell_2(S)$ I mean the set of functions $f:S\to\Bbb R$ such that $\{s\in S\,:\, f(s)\ne0\}$ is countable and $\sum_{f(s)\ne 0}\lvert f(s)\rvert^2<\infty$.

Comment: Completely agreed@Gae.S.

Answer (score 2):

All functionals on $\Bbb R$ are of the form $f(x)=ax$ for some $a \in \Bbb R$. The minimal topology $\mathcal{T}_w$ on $\Bbb R$ that makes all of these continuous (when the codomain has the usual topology $\mathcal{T}_e$) is of course $\mathcal{T}_e$: it's clear that $\mathcal{T}_w \subseteq \mathcal{T}_e$ as the latter is *one* topology that makes all these functionals continuous. And as $1_{\Bbb R}:=f(x)=x$ is just one of these functionals too, $1_{\Bbb R}: (\Bbb R,\mathcal{T}_w) \to (\Bbb R,\mathcal{T}_e)$ must be continuous so that $\mathcal{T}_e \subseteq \mathcal{T}_w$ by definition of continuity...

So two inclusions yield equality: $\mathcal{T}_e= \mathcal{T}_w$.